# Unity PolygonCollider2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня возникла небольшая проблема по поводу PolygonCollider2D.

Как изменять этот Collider скриптом? В теории я примерно осознаю, что это действие происходит через Path и Points, но не до конца понимаю синтаксис и что конкретно от меня требуется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала стоит разобраться, чем оперирует PolygonCollider2D.  Если посмотрим в окошко инспектора компонента PolygonCollider2D то видим следующее: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Points - массив точек (вершин), определяющих форму коллаидра. Этот массив разбит на Paths (пути), которые разбивают точки на связные группы. Точки из разных путей между собой не связаны. Пути добавлены для того, чтобы можно было задавать сложные формы коллаидра (например бублик и дырка от бублика будут описываться как раз двумя разными путями).

Теперь смотрим документацию по [PolygonCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.html).

В ней видим, что у нас есть доступ к свойству `.points`. Это массив элементов типа `Vector2`, который ( судя по другой статье в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html)) является неизменяемым (immutable). Это значит, что изменить какой-либо элемент этого массива мы не можем, но можем создать другой массив и присвоить его как новое значение свойства `.point`

Пример:

```
    PolygonCollider2D coll = gameObject.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
    var points = new [] {new Vector2(0, 1), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 0),};
    coll.points = points;
```

Экспериментальным путем выясняем, что это код заменит точки в коллаидре, таким образом, что мы получим 1 путь в котором будут 4 заданные нами точки.

При попытке изменить значение какого-либо элемента из массива `.points` синтаксических ошибок или ошибок компиляции мы не получим, но и при выполнении кода никакого результата мы не получим.

Пример:

```
coll.points[0] = new Vector2(10,10);
```

Этот код скомпилируется и выполнится, но никаких изменений в форме коллаидра не будет.

Также в документации есть метод [PolygonCollider2D.SetPath()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.SetPath.html), который принимает 2 параметра - `int` номер пути, который мы хотим отредактировать и `Vector2[]` массив точек, которые хотим установить в этом пути. В дополнении к этому метод [PolygonCollider2D.GetPath()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.GetPath.html), который позволяет получить массив точек в заданном пути.

Во всех случаях мы работаем с точками в локальный относительно редактируемого объекта координатах.